# Power set is an ordinal?

Tags: ordinals

I was told that the power set of an ordinal is not an ordinal in general.

However, if $\alpha$ is ordinal, then

$$\alpha+1 = \alpha \cup \{\alpha\}=\{\beta: \beta \in \alpha\} \cup \{\alpha\}= \{\beta: \beta \subsetneq \alpha\} \cup \{\alpha\}: \{\beta: \beta \subseteq \alpha\} = \mathcal{P}(\alpha)$$

Where do I go wrong? Is it wrong because the $\beta's$ are ordinals and not every subset of an ordinal is an ordinal?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely the reason. It is also clear that something is wrong since you have just claimed that $n+1 = n!$ for all natural $n$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft You mean $n+1 = 2^n$.

Comment: @JairTaylor Right. I got called away as I was typing the comment and got distracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the case that $\alpha \in \beta \Leftrightarrow \alpha \subsetneq \beta$. For example, $\{ 0, 2 \} \subsetneq 3$ but $\{ 0, 2 \} \not\in 3$.

Comment: Is $\{0,2\}$ an ordinal though?

Comment: @user745578: No, for example $1 \in 2 \in \{ 0, 2 \}$ but $1 \not\in \{ 0, 2 \}$, so it is not transitive.

Comment: Alright I see thanks!